# OpenLayers working in localhost but not on website

Tags: openlayers, react, deployment

I'm facing a very weird issue where the OpenLayers is working absolutely fine on localhost but the moment in push it to the web it doesn't render any images as shown below
[image]
I'm using OpenLayers `^7.1.0` with nextjs as follows:

```js
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import XYZ from "ol/source/XYZ";
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function OpenLayers() {
  useEffect(() => {
    new Map({
      target: "map",
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            crossOrigin: "anonymous",
          }),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        projection: "EPSG:4326",
        extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90],
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
      }),
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="container" >
        <div id="map" style={{ height: "500px", width: "1000px"}}></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any idea on what is happening here and how can I fix it?

There is no error in the console.

Comment: Can you attach your browser screenshot with address bar?

Comment: Try visiting this page - https://experientia.in/nasa-black-marble (its still under development).

Comment: Maybe you need to opt out of server side rendering? https://frontend-digest.com/how-to-disable-ssr-for-a-nextjs-page-d6b19aa350e3

Comment: That too doesn't work, I guess I'll need to switch back to react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's an issue with openlayers itself that doesn't allow it to render on next even with SSR disabled.

> OpenLayers does support virtual DOM, and it is being used successfully in thousands of React applications. But as stated elsewhere, it does not work in classic SSR (server side rendering) scenarios. Which does not mean that you cannot use OpenLayers on the server side to create static map images.
> @elamandeep, it would be interesting to hear where you're facing issues with an OpenLayers map in a virtual DOM. I'm not aware of any, except for a lack of automatic resize detection, which will very likely be fixed with [#14305](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/14305).

More info - https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14295#issuecomment-1316514225