# How to eliminate the gap in OpenLayers within the canvas for EPSG:4326 projection

Tags: openlayers, xyz, xyz-tiles, mapcanvas

I'm using XYZ tiles with `EPSG:4326` projection but tiles originally comes with `EPSG:3857`. For *3857* when I set the width and height to both 1000px there is no gaps and the tiles get filled up properly.

But when I set the width to 1000px and height to 500px with *4326* mode, it creates some gaps in top and bottom side as shown below
[image]

**Actual Canvas height and width**
[image]

This is my react code

```js
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import XYZ from "ol/source/XYZ";
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function OpenLayers() {
  useEffect(() => {
    new Map({
      target: "map",
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
            crossOrigin: "anonymous",
            tileSize: 256
          }),
        }),
      ],
      view: new View({
        projection: "EPSG:4326",
        extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90],
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2, maxZoom: 9
      }),
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="container" >
        <div id="map" style={{ height: "500px", width: "1000px"}}></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any idea on how to solve it and map the tiles fill the entire canvas? 
 I want to use this canvas as a texture to sphere in threejs and currently it creates hole at the poles due to those gaps which you can also see [in this example](https://codepen.io/gpanag/pen/JjKLZJj).

Comment: what if you set the extent to `[-180, -85, 180, 85]`

Comment: That for the suggestion it works well but when I try to apply that on sphere in threejs it just overlaps. you can try editing here on line 72 https://codepen.io/gpanag/pen/JjKLZJj so is there any middle ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poles are infinite in a mercator projection, so EPSG:3857 tiles have no coverage above approx. latitude 85 degrees.  That will result in transparency in the EPSG:4326 canvas.

You could set a background after rendering, for example:

```
layer.on('postrender', function (event) {
  event.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  event.context.fillStyle = 'black';
  event.context.fillRect(
    0,
    0,
    event.context.canvas.width,
    event.context.canvas.height
  );
  event.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
});
```

More info - [codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-bfcsqw?file=/main.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-bfcsqw?file=/main.js)

Comment: Do you mean that for vertical axis I should change extent from -85.051129 to 85.051129? I don't want to fill any colors within the canvas as it'll reflect in my threejs sphere which you can see with this example - https://codepen.io/gpanag/pen/JjKLZJj

Comment: No, you will need the poles for the sphere.  If transparent is not suitable use a background which matches the OSM https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-bfcsqw?file=/main.js

Comment: Oh, now I got what you were talking about filling the area. Saw the codesandbox and its brilliant. I never thought about it. Previously I thought I need to add one more layer of map just for top portion to cover hole on sphere but this is even better. Really thanks for helping me and especially for the code demo. I was stuck on it for few days but now its clear. Just a small request though, can you please give me any suggestion over this - https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/444829/213228 it'd really mean a lot to me. Thanks.